# How do I replace specific characters idiomatically in Rust?

Tags: regex, rust

So I have the string "Hello World!" and want to replace the "!" with "?" so that the new string is "Hello World?"

In Ruby we can do this easily with the `gsub` method:

```rb
"Hello World!".gsub("!", "?")
```

How to do this idiomatically in Rust?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can replace all occurrences of one string within another with [`str::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.replace):

```
let result = str::replace("Hello World!", "!", "?");
// Equivalently:
result = "Hello World!".replace("!", "?");
println!("{}", result); // => "Hello World?"
```

For more complex cases, you can use [`regex::Regex::replace_all`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.3/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace_all) from [regex](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.3/regex/index.html):

```
use regex::Regex;
let re = Regex::new(r"[A-Za-z]").unwrap();
let result = re.replace_all("Hello World!", "x");
println!("{}", result); // => "xxxxx xxxxx!"
```

Comment: Note that you can also call `replace` as a method on an `&str`, like this: `let result = "Hello World!".replace("!", "?");`.

Comment: please note: It is an anti-pattern to compile the same regular expression in a loop since compilation is typically expensive. See details in the crate description.

Answer (score 67):

Also you can use iterators and `match` expression:

```
let s:String = "Hello, world!".chars()
    .map(|x| match x { 
        '!' => '?', 
        'A'..='Z' => 'X', 
        'a'..='z' => 'x',
        _ => x
    }).collect();
println!("{}", s);// Xxxxx, xxxxx?
```

Comment: I like this because it can be generalized to handle more complicated cases that replace cannot handle, while being cheaper than a Regex (which admittedly can handle even more cases).

Comment: Rust playground warns not to use "..." range pattern anymore. Should use "..=" instead.

Comment: regex is pretty cheap!

Comment: What would you add if vowels should be removed? Can't find the solution when using this match solution.

Comment: Isn't it bad from performance perceptive? `char` in Rust is always 4 bytes, and common ASCI chars in Strings are 1 byte (because of UTF-8). This code will convert all character (many of 1 byte) to 4 bytes. Doesn't sound too performant.