# How to get strings parsed to floats with comma as decimal separator

Tags: string, rust, floating-point, type-conversion

I am trying to parse a string with the parse() function that is essentially a user input to a f32. There can be floating numbers entered with a comma as a decimal separator - how can I get that parsed as a f32?

So far parsing strings to floats works fine as long as the input is in the format "30" or "30.1" - as soon as the input is "30,1", I get a panic at Result::unwrap().
Is there a way to get parse to accept "," as a decimal separator?

This is my currently used code:

```
input.trim().parse().unwrap();
```

I expect parse taking "30" and "30,1" - Best if it would adhere to local decimal conventions

Comment: what are the rules regarding commas on 1,000s?

Comment: cos if you're only expecting a *single* comma or full stop, you could just find and replace commas to full stops, using https://stackoverflow.com/a/34606128/5986907, then parse to float

Comment: thousands separators are dots here, but I will just remove those in advance and then use the replace. It'd still be nice to have it use the actual local conventions

Comment: So how do you expect to disambiguate 30.123 and 30,123?

Comment: @SOFe he most likely doesn't care because his locale doesn't use `.` as a decimal separator.

Comment: @Luckystrik3 the standard library isn't locale-aware by design. You should pick a localization crate.

Comment: Copy the string and replace `,` with `.`.  Proceed as usual.

Comment: Thae are third party crates for that, such as [num-format](https://crates.io/crates/num-format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could just replace the comma with a dot before you pass it to parse.

```
fn main() {
    let input = "30,6";
    let val: f32 = input.trim().replace(',', ".").parse().unwrap();

    dbg!(val);
}
```

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

When the decimal separator is a comma, the thousands separator is usually a period. Therefore, it should be ensured that the latter isn't present.

```
let s = "12.345,67"
    .chars()
    .filter(|&c| c != '.' && c != ' ')
    .map(|c| if c == ',' { '.' } else { c })
    .collect::<String>();
```